# React sorting by specific word

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently sorting an array of JSON objects by a number.

```
myArray.sort((a, b) => a.scorePriority - b.scorePriority)
```

This works fine, but now, I need to sort it by High, Medium, Low, and ignore the number altogether.

```
[
    { scorePriority: 10, scoreValue: "low" },
    { scorePriority: 3, scoreValue: "high" },
    { scorePriority: 10, scoreValue: "medium" }
]
```

I need to sort by the scoreValue, where it can be low, medium, or high.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort with index based first array .With high to low `DESC` order

```js
var ind = ['high', 'medium', 'low'];
var arr = [{ scorePriority: 10, scoreValue: "low" }, { scorePriority: 10, scoreValue: "high" }]

arr = arr.sort((a,b) => {
 return ind.indexOf(a.scoreValue) -ind.indexOf(b.scoreValue)
})
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: @soldfor. always Welcome

Answer (score 5):

Use [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to sort alphabetically according to `scoreValue`:

```
array.sort((a, b) => a.scoreValue.localeCompare(b.scoreValue))
```

Or, if you want a predefined order (low -> medium -> high), use an ordering map whose keys are the possible `scoreValue` strings and whose values are the associated order for those keys:

```
array.sort((a, b) => {
  const orders = { 'low': 0, 'medium': 1, 'high': 2 };
  return orders[a.scoreValue] - orders[b.scoreValue];
});
```

```js
const array = [
  { scoreValue: 'low', scorePriority: 0 },
  { scoreValue: 'medium', scorePriority: 5 },
  { scoreValue: 'low', scorePriority: 6 },
  { scoreValue: 'high', scorePriority: 2 },
  { scoreValue: 'medium', scorePriority: 0 },
  { scoreValue: 'high', scorePriority: 10 }
];

const sorted1 = [...array].sort((a, b) => a.scoreValue.localeCompare(b.scoreValue));
console.log(sorted1);

const sorted2 = [...array].sort((a, b) => {
  const orders = { 'low': 0, 'medium': 1, 'high': 2 };
  return orders[a.scoreValue] - orders[b.scoreValue];
});
console.log(sorted2);
```

Comment: although you are not wrong, i found the answer from prasanth to fit my needs easier. appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#sortBy), you can do like this:

```
const items = [
  { scoreValue: 'low', scorePriority: 0 },
  { scoreValue: 'medium', scorePriority: 5 },
  { scoreValue: 'low', scorePriority: 6 },
  { scoreValue: 'high', scorePriority: 2 },
  { scoreValue: 'medium', scorePriority: 0 },
  { scoreValue: 'high', scorePriority: 10 }
];

_.sortBy(items, item => ["high", "medium", "low"].indexOf(item.scoreValue));
```